# How can I parse UTC date/time (String) into something more readable?

Tags: java

I have a String of a date and time like this: `2011-04-15T20:08:18Z`. I don't know much about date/time formats, but I think, and correct me if I'm wrong, that's its UTC format.

My question: what's the easiest way to parse this to a more normal format, in Java?

Comment: UTC is not a format, it's a timezone. It affects the value of the time, not the string representation.

Comment: The Z at the end (of an ISO-8601 date) means it's UTC... @Adrian is right that it's not a format.

Comment: Actually that is the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. It is a *very* "normal format", the most normal in that it is an officially defined international standard used by industry around the world. You'll find working with date-time to be much easier once you get used to it. How many countries around the world use the mm/dd/yyyy format with which you are familiar as an American? Let's [count them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country): US, and, uh, oh… Palou & Micronesia. And Canada when dealing with the US.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
String output = 
    Instant.parse ( "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z" )
           .atZone ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) )
           .format ( 
               DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                .withLocale ( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) 
           )
;
```

> vendredi 15 avril 2011 16 h 08 EDT

## Details

The [answer by Josh Pinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20484317/642706) is correct, but could be even simpler.

### java.time

In Java 8 and later, the bundled java.util.Date/Calendar classes are supplanted by the java.time framework defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Those classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) but are entirely re-architected.

The java.time framework is the official successor to Joda-Time. The creators of Joda-Time have advised we should migrate to java.time as soon as is convenient. Joda-Time continues to be updated and tweaked, but further innovation will be done only in java.time and its extensions in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

The bulk of java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

The equivalent for the Joda-Time code above is quite similar. Concepts are similar. And like Joda-Time, the java.time classes by default use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (versus [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) used by Joda-Time & java.util.Date).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z" );
```

Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Adjust into yet another time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId_NewYork = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_NewYork = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zoneId_NewYork );
```

To create strings in other formats beyond those of the `toString` methods, use the [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) classes. You can specify your own formatting pattern or let java.time localize automatically. Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for (a) the human language used in translation of name of month/day-of-week, and (b) cultural norms for period-versus-comma, order of the parts, and such.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.US );
String output = zdt_NewYork.format( formatter );
```

> Friday, April 15, 2011 4:08:18 PM EDT

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

### Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This section left intact for history.

### Pass String To Constructor

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) can take that string directly. Simply pass to a constructor on the [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class.

Joda-Time understands the standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) of date-times, and uses that format as its default.

### Example Code

Here is example code in Joda-Time 2.3 running in Java 7 on a Mac.

I show how to pass the string to a DateTime constructor, in two ways: With and without a time zone. Specifying a time zone solves many problems people encounter in doing date-time work. If left unspecified, you get the default time zone which can bring surprises when placed into production.

I also show how specify no time zone offset ([UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT) using the built-in constant `DateTimeZone.UTC`. That's what the `Z` on the end, short for `Zulu` time, means: No time zone offset (00:00).

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// Default time zone.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z" );

// Specified time zone.
DateTime dateTimeInKolkata = new DateTime( "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z", DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
DateTime dateTimeInNewYork = new DateTime( "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z", DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" ) );

// In UTC/GMT (no time zone offset).
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeInKolkata.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );

// Output in localized format.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.shortDateTime().withLocale( Locale.US );
String output_US = formatter.print( dateTimeInNewYork );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println("dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println("dateTimeInKolkata: " + dateTimeInKolkata );
System.out.println("dateTimeInNewYork: " + dateTimeInNewYork );
System.out.println("dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println("dateTime in US format: " + output_US );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2011-04-15T13:08:18.000-07:00
dateTimeInKolkata: 2011-04-16T01:38:18.000+05:30
dateTimeInNewYork: 2011-04-15T16:08:18.000-04:00
dateTimeUtc: 2011-04-15T20:08:18.000Z
dateTime in US format: 4/15/11 4:08 PM
```

Comment: Excellently documented.

Answer (score 44):

### Use [JodaTime](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time)

I kept getting parsing errors using the other solutions with the `Z` at the end of the format.

Instead, I opted to leverage [JodaTime](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time)'s excellent parsing functionality and was able to do the following very easily:

```
String timestamp = "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z";

DateTime dateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(timestamp);
```

This correctly recognizes the UTC timezone and allows you to then use JodaTime's extensive manipulation methods to get what you want out of it.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I thought the `Z` was needed (and I tested this at the time of posting). I removed the `Z` from my answer for now and giving you +1 for this since Joda time is a good answer. I didn't use Joda because he asked for the "easiest" which usually means Java-native.

Comment: @AndrewWhite First off, I agree with you about going Java-native but once I started digging into it, the benefits of JodaTime seemed to outweigh going native. The `Z` allows for timezones, which are incredibly important, however, it doesn't seem to "understand" the "Z" (standing for UTC timezone) in the ISO-8601 timestamp. JodaTime just does "the right thing".

Comment: @JoshPinter  No need for parser. The constructor for `DateTime` will parse an ISO 8601 string. `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z" );`  See my answer for more example code.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for looking into that Basil! I'll leave this here for posterity and in case there is a situation that requires the parser.

Comment: Thanks! It works like magic!=)
Used it this way:
DateTime dateTime= ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(dateString);
 dateTextView.setText(dateTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"));

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque Correct, with later versions of Java 8+: _"Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project."_

Answer (score 10):

Already has lot of answer but just wanted to update with **java 8** in case any one faced issues while parsing string date.

Generally we face two problems with dates

1. Parsing String to Date
2. Display Date in desired string format

`DateTimeFormatter` class in Java 8 can be used for both of these purpose.
Below methods try to provide solution to these issues.

**Method 1:**
Convert your UTC string to **Instant**. Using **Instant** you can create Date for any time-zone by providing time-zone string and use `DateTimeFormatter` to format date for display as you wish.

```
String dateString = "2016-07-13T18:08:50.118Z";
String tz = "America/Mexico_City";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy hh:mm a");
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(tz);

Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);

ZonedDateTime dateTimeInTz =ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);

System.out.println(dateTimeInTz.format(dtf));
```

**Method 2:**

Use `DateTimeFormatter` built in constants e.g `ISO_INSTANT` to parse string to `LocalDate`.
`ISO_INSTANT` can parse dates of pattern

**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX** e.g **'2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'**

```
LocalDate parsedDate
  = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);

DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
System.out.println(parsedDate.format(displayFormatter));
```

**Method 3:**

If your date string has much precision of time e.g it captures fraction of seconds as well as in this case **2016-07-13T18:08:50.118Z** then method 1 will work but method 2 will not work. If you try to parse it will throw `DateTimeException` Since `ISO_INSTANT` formatter will not be able to parse fraction of seconds as you can see from its pattern.
In this case you will have to create a **custom** `DateTimeFormatter` by providing date pattern as below.

```
LocalDate localDate 
= LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));
```

Taken from a [blog link](http://techcresendo.com/2016/07/14/parsing-string-datetimeformatter-java-8/) written by me.

Comment: What about this `2019-10-09T00:44:17.453576+00:00`

Answer (score 9):

[The Java 7 version of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) supports ISO-8601 time zones using the uppercase letter `X`.

```
String string = "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z";
DateFormat iso8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date date = iso8601.parse(string);
```

If you're stuck with Java 6 or earlier, the answer recommending JodaTime is a safe bet.

Comment: There is a value in answers for the post-Jodatime world after Java has atoned for some of its sins.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the following format:

```java
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date parse = simpleDateFormat.parse( "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z" );
```

Comment: Using a format string of "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" with the input provided by the asker of the question fails with a java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z"

Answer (score 1):

I had a parse error in Andrew White solution.
Adding the single quote around the Z solved the issue

```
DateFormat m_ISO8601Local = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Answer (score 1):

the pattern in @khmarbaise answer worked for me, here's the utility method I extracted (note that the Z is omitted from the pattern string):

```
/**
 * Converts an ISO-8601 formatted UTC timestamp.
 *
 * @return The parsed {@link Date}, or null.
 */
@Nullable
public static Date fromIsoUtcString(String isoUtcString) {
    DateFormat isoUtcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    isoUtcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    try {
        return isoUtcFormat.parse(isoUtcString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the older versions of JDK (6 down) it may be useful.

Getting rid of trailing 'Z' and replacing it literally with 'UTC' timezone display name - then parsing the whole string using proper simple date formatter.

```
String timeZuluVal = "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z";
timeZuluVal = timeZuluVal.substring( 0, timeZuluVal.length() - 2 ); // strip 'Z';
timeZuluVal += " " + TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ).getDisplayName();
DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss zzzz" );
Date dateVal = simpleDateFormat.parse( timeZuluVal );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Joda Time**

```
public static final String SERVER_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss";

public static DateTime getDateTimeFromUTC(String time) {
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(SERVER_TIME_FORMAT).withZoneUTC();

        Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateTimeZone currentTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(localTime.getTimeZone());
        return dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(time).toDateTime().withZone(currentTimeZone);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return DateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).