# How to correctly convert a timestring to a date object

Tags: java, android, epoch

I'm having trouble converting a time string into an accurate Date object representation

The server that I'm communicating with will provide a UTC time value such as this.

```
2013-01-02T05:32:02.8358602Z
```

When I try the following code, I end up with a millisecond count that is nearly 2hr15min ahead of the expected UTC.

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault());
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));                   
Date date = inputFormat.parse("2013-01-02T05:32:02.8358602Z");
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse UTC date/time (String) into something more readable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543174/how-can-i-parse-utc-date-time-string-into-something-more-readable)

Comment: Thanks for the suggested link, but I don't believe it's a duplicate. I wasn't looking to improve the readability, rather accurately convert the string to a Date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date d = format.parse(fileDate);
```

Must specify the correct format in the **SimpleDateFormat()** constructor.

Edited:

```
public String getconvertdate1(String date)
{
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date parsed = null; // should not be initialized first else current date will be printed in case of a parse exception
    try
    {
        parsed = inputFormat.parse(date);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);
    return outputText;
}
```

And also try this format with my above method: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Comment: Unfortunately that throws a parse exception

Comment: I had worked with that, Jayamohan....@Redshirt, i have posted another answer see, edited.

Comment: I called your method with the input _getconvertdate1("2013-01-02T05:32:02.8358602Z");_ Still am getting _java.text.ParseException_

Comment: adding the 'T' to the inputFormat works when using the edited answer. The only real difference in your code compared to mine now is that you instantiate the Date object before assigning to it... Not going to try and figure out why, just happy it works.

Comment: @Jayamohan: Can't you see the format specified above...its "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" and you are specifying "YYYY MM DD HH:MM:SS" I think.....you can follow your pattern of date and for that you have to specify the correct format in the constructor of SimpleDateFormat()....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SimpleDateFormat takes 8358602 is not a fraction of a second it is then number if millis = 8358602 ms. By default SimpleDateFormat is in "lenient" mode, that's why it accepts 8358602, it will also accept 99 in day field and will move extra days to month field and so on. If you switch strict mode on as SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(true) you will get ParseException, because max value for millis is 999.

I can offer a workaround. Your date comes in W3C XML Schema 1.0 date/time format with fractional second. For this case javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar is what you need. This works

```
DatatypeFactory dtf = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar c = dtf.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2013-01-02T05:32:02.8358602Z");
System.out.println(c.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
```

and prints

```
Wed Jan 02 07:32:02 EET 2013
```

note that EET is GMT+2