# Java Can't Parse UTC Date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, spring-mvc, jodatime

Why am I getting an error below?  It happens only with some dates.

```
 Helper.getDate("2014-01-09T17:10:14Z", "dd-MM-yyyy");

public static Date getDate(String date, String format) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

    try {
        return df.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        log.error("getDate", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your format is wrong.

Comment: What is it you expect/want the code to actually do?

Comment: To return a valid Date object.

Comment: Maybe this can help you:

[Parce UTC Date][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543174/how-can-i-parse-utc-date-time-string-into-something-more-readable

Comment: Why don't you use jodatime API? `new Datetime.parse(date)` should be enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This date:

`"2014-01-09T17:10:14Z"`

has a format of
`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

(or in Java 7 `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`)

So of course it will be impossible to parse it with a format `dd-MM-yyyy`.

The formatting string needs to be compatible with the input!

(Note I gave a literal Z, this is back compatible.  Java 7 actually understands ISO8601 and you could use an X there to have it actually be parsed.)

Answer (score 0):

That string `2014-01-09T17:10:14Z` is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for date-times.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library takes such standard strings directly in its [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor. No need for formatters/parsers.

Easy one liner…
(Feed standard string to constructor of DateTime, then convert the DateTime instance to a java.util.Date instance)

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

java.util.Date date = new DateTime( "2014-01-09T17:10:14Z" ).toDate();
```

Dump to console, and show `DateTime` values for comparison…

```java
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + new DateTime( "2014-01-09T17:10:14Z" ) );
System.out.println( "dateTime in UTC: " + new DateTime( "2014-01-09T17:10:14Z" ).toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
date: Thu Jan 09 09:10:14 PST 2014
dateTime: 2014-01-09T09:10:14.000-08:00
dateTime in UTC: 2014-01-09T17:10:14.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Already has lot of answer but just wanted to update with **java 8**.

Generally we face two problems with dates

1. Parsing String to Date
2. Display Date in desired string format

`DateTimeFormatter` class in Java 8 can be used for both of these purpose.
Below methods try to provide solution to these issues.

**Method 1:**
Convert your UTC string to **Instant**. Using **Instant** you can create Date for any time-zone by providing time-zone string and use `DateTimeFormatter` to format date for display as you wish.

```
String dateString = "2016-07-13T18:08:50.118Z";
String tz = "America/Mexico_City";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy hh:mm a");
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(tz);

Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);

ZonedDateTime dateTimeInTz =ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
System.out.println(dateTimeInTz.format(dtf));
```

**Method 2:**

Use `DateTimeFormatter` built in constants e.g `ISO_INSTANT` to parse string to `LocalDate`.
`ISO_INSTANT` can parse dates of pattern

**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX** e.g **'2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'**

```
LocalDate parsedDate
  = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);

DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
System.out.println(parsedDate.format(displayFormatter));
```

**Method 3:**

If your date string has much precision of time e.g it captures fraction of seconds as well as in this case **2016-07-13T18:08:50.118Z** then method 1 will work but method 2 will not work. If you try to parse it will throw `DateTimeException` Since `ISO_INSTANT` formatter will not be able to parse fraction of seconds as you can see from its pattern.
In this case you will have to create a **custom** `DateTimeFormatter` by providing date pattern as below.

```
LocalDate localDate 
= LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));
```