# How to parse JSON date time in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have looked everywhere but I couldn't find anything about parsing a date time json object in android.

I am trying to convert this JSON `2016-08-12T20:07:59.518451`to get **ONLY** the time like this `20:07` and format it in the correct time zone UTC/GMT +1 hour.

I could do it in javascript, but I wasn't able to get it right in Java/Android.

Is there a method that handle this for me or will I need to use Regex to get the correct time?

EDIT: here is the code. expectedArrival is the one with the json date/time and I only want to get the time with UTC/GMT +1 hour time zone.

```
public class JSONTaskArrivals extends AsyncTask<String, String,List<ArrivalItem>> {

    @Override
    protected List<ArrivalItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
        //json
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJSON = buffer.toString();
            JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finalJSON);
            List<ArrivalItem> arrivalItems = new ArrayList<>();
            int time = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                ArrivalItem item = new ArrivalItem();
                item.setDestination(finalObject.getString("destinationName"));
                item.setEstimated(finalObject.getString("expectedArrival"));
                time = finalObject.getInt("timeToStation")/60;
                if(time < 1){
                    item.setLive("Due");
                }else{
                    item.setLive(Integer.toString(time)+" mins");
                }

                arrivalItems.add(item);
            }

            return arrivalItems;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null){
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ArrivalItem> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ArrivalsAdapter adapter = new ArrivalsAdapter(ArrivalsActivity.this, R.layout.arrivals_row, result);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.arrivals_listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may try doing it manually(for eg, if you are in India, add 5hr 30min to time you recieved and increment corresponding date if it changes too)

Comment: @HarshitKumar wasn't really helpful. I want to know how to get the time from that JSON date time object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal check this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543174/how-can-i-parse-utc-date-time-string-into-something-more-readable

Comment: post the code so we can improve the help....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I have the code up now

Comment: @DanielOMensah Your example date-time string has no indication of an offset-from-UTC or time zone. Can we presume an offset or time zone? Perhaps UTC?

Comment: No such thing as a JSON date-time. JSON [defines very few data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example).

Comment: @DanielOMensah Way too much code here. Learn to make a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

1. That json has a key:val with the date, then get the date, (its for sure in the json as string)
2. then parse that String as Date.
3. use a [SimpleDateFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and format the reconstructed date to be represented as you want/need..

Comment: This is the correct answer, looks to be a format of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff`

Answer (score 3):

No such thing as a “JSON date-time”. JSON defines [very few data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example).

## String → Instant → OffsetDateTime → LocalTime

If your input string `2016-08-12T20:07:59.518451` represents a moment in UTC, append a `Z` (short for Zulu, means UTC).

```
String input = "2016-08-12T20:07:59.518451" + "Z" ;
```

Then parse as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). So your example input with [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) fits nicely.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
```

Adjust into your desired offset-from-UTC.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 1 ); // One hour ahead UTC.
```

Apply to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset );
```

If you want only the time-of-day from that `OffsetDateTime` extract a `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime lt = odt.toLocalTime(); // Example: 20:39
```

If you want other than the ISO 8601 format used by the `toString` method, use a `DateTimeFormatter` object. Many examples found if you search on Stack Overflow.

Better to use a time zone, if known, rather than a mere offset. Produces a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method to split date and time and store it another two variable..
So now you have seprate values of date and time..